# Doxygen style documentation in Xcode 6, linking to TypeDef documentation

Tags: xcode6, doxygen

I'm trying to properly document a custom class i have.

My class has a custom enumeration and a custom function.
What I want to achieve is in the custom function, provide a link to the typedef enumeration documentation, so the user can see the enumeration states directly.

Here is what I did and does fail:

```
/** @file AppSetingsManager */

///Enumerator states for Facebook Login
typedef enum {
    kFBUserLogedIn = 1, /**< Login from Facebook Finished */
    kFBUploadedData = 2, /** We have completed uploading user's data to our backend */
    kFBDidGetWritePermission = 3, /** We did obtain write permission from Facebook */
    KFBFinsishedWithExistingAccount = 4, /** Login completed, user had already an account on platform */
    KFBFinsishedWithNewAccount = 5 /**< Sign Up completed, a new user account was created */
} FaceBookLoginState;

/**
 * Performs login on Facebook with obj-c blocks
 *
 * @param dismissed The block to be executed after each step of the Login Process <b>Does return an FaceBookLoginState enumerator type of the login process stage</b>
 * @param cancelled The block to be executed in case the login process fails <b>Does return a String with the failure error</b>
 * @brief Facebook Login Function with blocks
 * @see AppSetingsManager#FaceBookLoginState
 */
- (void)loginFacebook:(DidFinishFBLogin)dismissed onCancel:(DidFailFBLogin)failed;
```

Now this does look like this on Xcode:

[image: Xcode documentation popup]

As you can see it does not link to the enumerator states documentation.
I tried various approaches like `@see typedef ::FaceBookLoginState` and others, but none seem to work.

Anyone knows if this can be done and if yes, how ?

Comment: You should remove the argument for @file, and use #FaceBookLoginState to refer to the enum value. This should work in the doxygen output. Whether also XCode supports this, is a different story. XCode only supports a small subset of all doxygen markup.

Comment: I guess it doesn't work in Xcode, as I did what you suggested. Thank you.